# Mapping a network drive from Windows 10 to Windows 2016 Server

Tags: windows-server-2016, network-share, windows-10

I can ping the IP address of Windows 2016 server from my Windows 10 local computer. I can also connect remotely to Windows 2016 server as an Administrator with full privileges. I created a folder named `ImportantDocs` in C folder and granted share privilege of read/write to everyone.

Now when I try to map a network drive from my local desktop by giving a drive letter Z and then giving in field `\\ipaddress of remote desktop\ImportantDocs` I get error like -

> > The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occured:
> >
> > We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try again. If you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential

How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you in a domain environement ?

Comment: Yes, I am in a domain environment.

Comment: Why exactly are you using the IP address instead of the server name?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your client could not authenticate against your domain. Make sure, your DC is reachable, firewalls are configured properly, DNS for your AD ist working fine (on both ends) and test access to the file share from your client through the UNC path (`\\SERVERNAME.FQDN.TLC`).

Opening up just the Server (`\\servername`) will display all avaible shared folders. If you can see them but can not open them, NTFS rights are improper for this user.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. When mapping a drive from my local Windows 10, I have to check mark connect using different credentials. After that I should choose login using different account. Then in username I should write the username prefixed by IPAddress (This prefix is important). Example `ipaddress\username` Then give server password and you would be able to see the shared folder contents.

Comment: Then this is no domain share...